# Implementing notification dialogs that don't steal focus from full-screen apps?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to implement a notification window by subclassing `QDialog`. It should be on top of other windows, but I don't want it to steal focus from other windows for obvious reasons. I'm also concerned that it would interfere with full-screen applications like videos and games.

How do I go about implementing this? Are there any common programming and UX practices I might want to know about?

Answer (score 3):

It appears quite an old topic. However, I did not see anyone posting a proper answer that just works, so I am posting my solution to the same problem I have been facing recently.

First of all, if you want your dialog not to steal focus from other dialogs or input fields, you should set the following property: *Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating*. Using this property, window (dialog is also a window) will be shown without being activated. Then, probably you will want to customize your dialog to your needs, and you will want this dialog to be shown on top. So, the following Window flags can be set in order to achieve such a result in a cross-platform manner: *Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus*.

The code below is one of the examples to achieve a dialog that is modeless, and does not steal focus from anyone (assuming *dialog* is a variable pointing to the valid instance of QDialog):

```
dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating, true);
dialog->setWindowFlags(dialog.windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus);
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it but it looks like

```
my_dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowFlags | ... | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

should work, in conjunction with making it modeless.

Comment: I've removed the correct answer marker from your post because sometimes the popup steals focus from my current window. This is not desired behavior. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a [non modal dialog](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs):

> A modeless dialog is a dialog that operates independently of other
>   windows in the same application. Find and replace dialogs in
>   word-processors are often modeless to allow the user to interact with
>   both the application's main window and with the dialog.

In order to achive that you need to call the [`show`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show) function and not the [`exec`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec) one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this only causes the window to operate independently of its parent. It still won't stay on top when the user ALT+TABs.

Comment: A QDialog is a top level window. You can use the `raise` function if you want to ensure that it will be on top of the parent widget's stack. Using `show`, the dialog will be visible and you will be able to interact with the other windows of the application. If you want to make the dialog visible throughout the application then you could set the main window as its parent. I am not sure what happens with the ALT+TABs

Comment: When the user presses ALT+TAB (or gives focus to a full-screen window), the QDialog is no longer on top of other windows. This is not desired behavior for an [MSN Messenger-like](http://www.donkhuth.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/saosang.jpg) notification like the one I'm trying to achieve.